# Exact sequence via $[-,-]_*$ with HEP

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence

I was wondering if it is possible to identify the sequence

$$[C(f),Z]_* \rightarrow[Y,Z]_* \rightarrow [X,Z]_*
$$

induced by the sequence of based maps between pointed spaces
$$ X \rightarrow Y \hookrightarrow C(f)$$ if the pair (Y,X) has HEP.